# Filtering free text search with faceted search navigation

Tags: search, search-results, faceted-search

Once a user makes a free text search from the homepage, we aim to predict the branch and leaf with tree view.

When the user selects the predicted tree view search query or types a unique search query should we match each search token with a filter tag?

And Should we populate the facet tokens with the free text search tokens then allow the user to edit those tokens?

Answer (score 2):

Your description is a little confusing. So I'll state general information about facetted search.

1. Almost everybody know how to use it. Amazon have it since a long time and most people 'at least' browse Amazon.
2. It is used to narrow search results, or browse inside categories. Mostly because people hate paging and less options is actually better than 1000s of results to decide.
3. Facet tokens are only values of properties that your search results items have, for example: 'sneakers' -> type: high/low, color: black/white/red. But they are some special like price range.
4. You only display the tokens available within the search results. Otherwise if the user select one it will navigate to a empty page with no results.
5. Displaying the number of items the token will display is very valuable to the user.